# Deploying asciidoc documentation to Azure as static web app

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to deploy my documentation generated by AsciiDoc to Azure as a Azure Static Web App.

I am first trying to deploy it from the CLI to see if everything is correct before I will implement it in the build pipeline with `AzureStaticWebApp@0`.

My project structure looks as follows:

```
Root
-build                      <-- All inside this folder gets created by AsciiDoc 
--dist
---MyAsciiDoc.zip
--docs
---index.html               <-- I expect this to be the root of the app being deployed
---subfolder
----pageInfo1.html
staticwebapp.config.json
swa.cli.config.json
README.MD
```

With the swa.cli.config.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/azure/static-web-apps-cli/schema",
  "default": {
    "configurations": {
      "my-first-app": {
        "appLocation": "/build/docs",
        "outputLocation": "."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running this form the command line:

`swa deploy .\my-first-app-root-folder\ --deployment-token **** --verbose=silly`

The app deploys successful but nothing is displayed when I go to the URL `http://randomURL`

If I do add an `index.html` to the root of my project (on the same level as the `README.MD`) it does work and displays the `index.html` of the root project. But the root `index.html` must be the one inside my `docs` folder.

Then if I navigate to `http://randomURL/build/docs/index.html` I can access the contents of that index.html.

What am I doing wrong here to deploy the docs folder as the root of the project in order for `http://randomURL/index.html` to point to the one in my `docs` folder?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

The swa.cli.config.json being:

```
{
 "configurations": {
  "my-first-app": {
   "appLocation": "./build/docs",
   "outputLocation": "."
  }
 }
}
```

Being inside the root folder running the following command (where the first argument is the name of the config and not the root folder name):

`swa deploy my-first-app --deployment-token *** --verbose=silly`